# Seeking attention towards the unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, unanswered-questions

Is there a way to re-iterate the attention of the readers towards my questions which  remains unanswered for a long time? Can I ask them again?

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9245/50583 And no, please don't repost unanswered questions, they will simply get closed as a duplicate of the earlier questions.