# Are questions regarding gravitational waves allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

A question I have is "We know gravitational waves exist, but how do we detect them?"

"I have heard astronomers talk about gravitational waves being created when two black holes collide or when two neutron stars collide."

- note that this question idea is not complete

Comment: Meta is not a sandbox for you to pitch every question you have. I mentioned this under my last answer.

Comment: again can't ask questions on main

Comment: How did you expect posting on meta to solve that though? You won't get answers to that here, and it's just consuming a lot of peoples' time since it's extremely clear that you hadn't tried searching the site for similar questions. (Or the rest of the internet for that matter, since it's a very common question and is addressed by dozens of articles) You're also submerging important meta questions.

Comment: The rate restrictions are imposed to suggest that you should take some time off to think about why the questions weren't well-received, and to think about how to write better questions. Asking the questions you have on meta and saying "Can I ask this?" is making _other_ people try to fix those questions and direct you to duplicates with answers, which, in my opinion, isn't good form.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think it's appropriate to regularly use meta as a sandbox for questions.

Comment: @Chair I checked if this question was a duplicate and it is not

Comment: I think you're missing my point... it's not the downvoters' fault, as you seem to imply. You asked why your questions are downvoted, and you got the reasons why people don't think your questions should be posted in that form. Regarding the duplicate, I strongly believe that you didn't search, because the posts linked in rob's answer are _exact_ duplicates. Perhaps you're using the wrong search terms? try "how do we detect gravitational waves physics stack exchange" on google. I just tried that; it works.

Comment: I think you missed the this idea is not complete part of my question and i have a Search engine you do not have

Comment: If that search engine doesn't work, I strongly recommend google... it's free and it works really well! Your question includes "We know gravitational waves exist", but there's no reason why that affects answers, so you shouldn't be adding that to a search. The hypothesizing of gravitational waves is a completely different question. The good technique for searching is to cut out the fluff which could exclude results.

Comment: I don't want to continue this discussion. It doesn't matter if you have some fancy access to hard-to-find resources. There are free, accessible stuff indexed by google, and it's very unlikely that you can't use those instead.

Comment: and it is the only search engine that has a .00000000000000000000000000000000001 second search result speed

Comment: I'm sorry, this is beginning to sound like you're fabricating your side of this discussion. I've told you that you should simply use google, and resort to that 'supposed' slow search engine _only when the standard one doesn't work_.

Comment: You shouldn't ask 'unofficial physics questions' on meta. That's misusing the site. [Some sites have specific provision for sandboxes on the meta sites](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6168) but it's not that hard to ask questions on physics SE, so we don't do that. It's a bad practice to bounce all your questions off meta to avoid getting banned. Do your research and try to be coherent, don't try to deceive readers, and make sure it's about physics; if you do that, your question on the main site will be well received, I guarantee that.

Comment: I don't get it?  You're banned on main, so now you're asking questions on meta about questions that you can't even ask right now on main?  Can you see how this might seem like you're wasting people's time here?  By the way, Chair was just explaining that they were able to use google and find the thing you couldn't find with your special search engine.  If this special search engine isn't giving you good hits on this site, it makes sense to use something that is known to work pretty well, like google.

Comment: I have personal Search engine that is absurdly fast

Comment: @Luna You seem to be ignoring or missing the point every time.  The _speed_ of your search engine isn't that relevant here.  We are talking about the quality of results.  It doesn't matter how fast the search engine is if it _can't find what you are looking for_.  It defeats the purpose.  That is why Chair suggested using google instead of this "personal search engine"; because clearly your personal search engine cannot be trusted to give good results for physics stack exchange.

Comment: it has them but they are way in the back

Comment: Google (and presumably the other staples like yahoo/bing) is not that slow. If you actually have some fancy search engine (which I doubt), you can still use google without loosing too much time. I strongly doubt that you (or anyone) will be able to do anything meaningful in that kind of a time difference. I've said this before and I'll say it again... if you're making a lot of this up, it's really not helping your cause and it certainly won't get you closer to writing well-received questions.

Comment: @Luna If you would have taken the time you spend on Meta, to search on Google instead, you would have learned a whole lot more about gravitational waves and how they are detected. Even the wikipedia article starts out with it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational-wave_observatory

Comment: The comments on this post were getting a little out of control. I've deleted some entirely irrelevant ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In general, any topic for which a [tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags) exists is not categorically off-topic. In this case, there already 723 questions tagged [gravitational-waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravitational-waves), 580 of which are not closed, so it seems safe to say that such questions are allowed.
2. If you are just looking for basic information about a topic, as in that you know the name but not much else, we generally expect you to show due diligence in doing prior research, which at the very least includes looking for (and reading) the Wikipedia article on the topic, if one exists, and searching the internet for your question or keywords from it with your favourite search engine. If you have done so and still feel there's something left to know, it is *essential* that you reference the knowledge you already have. Only that way answerers will know what they need to explain, and only that way can questions become focused enough so that they are not effectively asking for a book-length introduction to the topic.

Comment: ok thank you, my question about magnets on main needs more attention can I do anything to help with that?

Comment: @Luna see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9245/50583

Comment: There are a few tags that I would consider exceptions to your point #1, like [tag:soft-question] and [tag:mathematics] - that is, for those particular tags, I would not advise a person to take the existence of the tag as evidence in favor of a question on that topic being within the site's scope.

Comment: Ok @DavidZ I assume you have read most or all of my questions I have seen you on a lot of them

Comment: @DavidZ If you want to get pedantic, then [tag:soft-question] is not a "topic", so my #1 doesn't apply to it :P

Comment: Ah, yes that's true. :-) But I wouldn't trust that everyone is going to make that distinction in the same way - that is, people might take the existence of the tag as an indicator that it's fine to ask soft questions, and I think it's worth pointing out that that's not the case for that particular tag.

Comment: I am not sure if you were responding to both comments or not

Comment: @DavidZ were you addressing both of us?

Comment: wait are you saing my 4D one when it had voloume it was not off topic

Answer (score 4):

ACuriousMind has given a good answer to your question in general.

To address your proposed question specifically, searching the tag [gravitational-waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravitational-waves) for "detect" brings up [this poor question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81208/44126) and [this better question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304212/44126) among about four hundred others.  The question as you describe it here sounds like an exact duplicate of the first, but a helpful flagger might link it to another more comprehensive question like the second.

For what it's worth, repeatedly asking "would such-and-such a question be on-topic?" is not really a good use of Meta.  It's worked out for you [twice now](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11046/44126), but a better long-term strategy is for you to spend more time reading good questions on the subjects that interest you.

Comment: I only asked because I had to wait to ask a question on main

Comment: @Luna You can get the list of your deleted questions here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/220173 . **Check the list now, and save their links somewhere! Later you won't have any way to get access to the list of your deleted posts any more! But if you save them now, later you might be able to fix them and even get an undelete.**

Comment: @peterh I have no deleted question

Comment: @Luna Then you have no reason to complain, the system treats you well. At least this is what I see on your scores. Well, I think that 4d object volume question shouldn't have been closed as homework, it was clearly not a homework. It might be "too broad", although I think a clear answer still could be given. The problem is that you need to learn integrals with multiple variables to calculate it, and you probably can't do that. But believe me, it is really easy (at least in theory, for physical objects).

Comment: 1 - voted question will prevent me from asking eventually

Comment: @Luna It is bad. Can you ask questions now?

Comment: @Luna As far I know, there are multiple question bans depending on, how bad are your scores. You are probably in the lightest one, so you will likely out in some weeks. Try to collect rep by writing answers.